# Finding/Showing solution $y'=Ay$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $$A(x)=\begin{pmatrix} -x^2 & 1 \\ 2x-x^4-\frac{x}{ln(x)} & x^2+\frac{1}{x ln(x)}\end{pmatrix}$$
>   Show that a solution of $y'=Ay$ looks like  $y_1(x)=\begin{pmatrix} x^a\\x^b\end{pmatrix}$ for $a,b \in \Bbb R$ constants.

My attempt:

$y'=\begin{pmatrix} ax^{a-1}\\ bx^{b-1}\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} -x^2 & 1 \\ 2x-x^4-\frac{x}{ln(x)} & x^2+\frac{1}{x ln(x)}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x^a\\x^b\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} -x^{a+2}+x^b\\2x^{1+a}-x^{4+a}-\frac{x^{1+a}}{ln(x)} +x^{2+b}+\frac{x^b-1}{ln(x)}\end{pmatrix}=Ay$

$\Rightarrow a=-x^{3+b}$ and now if I put this in the second equation I don't get the same result, that's why have another attempt:

The eigenvalues of $A(x) $ are $\lambda_1,_2=\frac{1}{2xln(x)} \frac{+}{-}\frac{1}{2xln(x)} \sqrt{1+ln(x)8x^3}$ and now I've some trouble with calculating the eigenvectors.

I just don't know how to continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the question means that we can find such a solution (i.e. a solution in this form) with **some particular** choice of $a$ and $b$, not that it's true for any $a$ and $b$. Your derivatives and matrix multiplication are correct. And now your task is to find $a$ and $b$ that satisfy the two equations. Let's start with the first one:
$$-x^{a+2}+x^b=ax^{a-1}.$$
For this to be an identity (true for all $x$), $a$ has to be zero, because otherwise the terms $-x^{a+2}$ and $ax^{a-1}$ would have different powers and the equality wouldn't hold. $a=0$ "kills" the term on the right-hand side. Now you can find the only value of $b$ that will make the left-hand side vanish as well. And finally, you can verify that with these values of $a$ and $b$ the second equation also turns into an identity.